# ValueListnable Builder not refreshing Charts

Tags: android, iphone, windows, flutter

So I had asked a question about updating charts by accessing data from a box and someone had suggested using ValueListnableBuilder. (Can't find that answer now, I don't know if it got deleted TT_TT). I tried to make it work without that initially and it was working, but now that I added a second chart to the page, I was faced with the same issue, the values didn't update until and unless I used hot reload. So I reverted back to using ValueListnableBuilder and that got my Heat Map working but my percent indicator won't work. For some reason, the values for `db.habitList.length` and `db.countCompleted()` return 0s. I don't Understand why `db.loadHeatmap()` works fine but the other two don't.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_habits/components/charts.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:my_habits/data/database.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyStats extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStats({super.key});

  final _myBox = Hive.box('myBox');

  HabitDatabase db = HabitDatabase();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //db.loadHeatMap();
    //print(db.loadHeatMap());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Consistency is Key!'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ValueListenableBuilder<Box<dynamic>>(
            valueListenable: _myBox.listenable(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, Box<dynamic> box, _) {
              db.loadHeatMap();
              int t = db.habitList.length;
              int c = db.countCompleted();
              print("ValueListenableBuilder triggered, $t, $c");
              return ListView(
                children: [
                  MonthlySummary(
                    datasets: db.heatMapDataSet,
                    startDate: _myBox.get("START_DATE"),
                  ),
                  MyProgressBar(
                    total: t,
                    complete: c,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
    );
  }
```

As mentioned before, I am a bit confused as to why one reference to the database works while the other two do not.

Please help! I am a total beginner with this.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers! :)